# Internet connection inside Docker container in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes pod based on jenkins/slave container to which I mount docker socket and docker binary file with necessary kernel module in privileged mode. Inside that pod I build Docker image basing on which I run docker container. Inside that container I don't have Internet connection at all because pod container uses flannel network (198.x.x.x) and that container uses bridged docker network (172.x.x.x) which is not available inside pod container. How can I make Internet to be available inside the second container which is being created inside Kubernetes pod container? Using Docker API in Jenkins pipeline is not a solution for me as long as it limits output of error logs and I can not commit changes made in the second container because of immediate removing of that container after build.

Comment: You may refer this for your answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299428/no-internet-connectivity-inside-docker-container-running-inside-kubernetes-with/49408621#49408621](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299428/no-internet-connectivity-inside-docker-container-running-inside-kubernetes-with/49408621#49408621)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this article will help you with this issue, [JENKINS DECLARATIVE PIPELINES WITH KUBERNETES](https://radu-matei.com/blog/kubernetes-jenkins-azure/#configuring-jenkins-to-dinamically-spawn-agents-docker-containers-for-builds) . This article shows a full stack on how to setup Jenkins in Kubernetes and also involves idea about Docker in Docker.

Based on my thought, we could mark as pod container as `container1` and container in pod as `container2`.

I think `container1` and `container2` should locate in the same host and shared the same docker engine. So flannel network with docker network should setup together.

As my idea, network flow for `container2` should be from `container2` -> `docker0` -> `host`, should be not with `container1`.

Just let me know if this should be reasonable, or we could discuss together, I think this question is very interesting.

Comment: Hi Zhao, I was able to figure out the issue. My Hypervisor was instantly rebooted 5 days ago and after reboot I noticed that firewall rule was not applied for Docker bridge. Once I added the next rule: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE the issue has gone. I have already added autostart script which will apply this rule in case of reboot.

Comment: @zaho I am also struggling with the same problem, I have my jenkins hosted as pod inside docker container and this jenkins spawns jenkins slave as K8s pod and in this slave I am building my dockerfile, here starts the problem, if I have any statement in dockerfile that needes internet connection(yum install xyz) then my slave container not able to access the internet. My slaves are using the host docker engine and I have mapped docker.sock inside the container. Any thought on this?